# login to Google OK but not Google Drive

Tags: linux, browser, privacy, google-drive, cookies

On my Linux laptop I have recently changed my Privacy preferences to never allow cookies, and then making exceptions for `https://google.com` and Google in my country, plus `https://accounts.google.com` (and for my country), and `https://calendar.google.com` and `https://drive.google.com`.

Now I can login to Google and Google Calendar without having to allow cookies in general. But Google Drive, after showing my name and profile picture, greys out the screen and shows a dialog "`You are not signed in. You are signed out. Sign back in, then click 'Retry'.`" and a `Retry` button. Clicking it, or clicking refresh, returns to the same screen.

Is it possible to have Google Drive access via the browser without allowing cookies in general?